# Gremlin - select a vertex, create new vertices and edges in single query

Tags: graph-databases, gremlin, tinkerpop, janusgraph

I have a user vertex already created.

```
g.V().has('user','username','vipul').as('user')
```

I want to create a new 'group' vertex with some properties and also a new 'options' vertex with some other properties.

```
g.addV(label,'group','group_name','DC11').as('group')
g.addV(label,'options','command_line_arguments','-D -n').as('options')
```

Now I want to create an edge from user to group and another edge from group to options.

```
user ---> group,   group ---> options
```

Can these queries be combined, selecting a vertex, creating new vertices and then creating new edges?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply chain the steps together:

```
g.V().has('user','username','vipul').as('user').
  addV('group').property('group_name','DC11').as('group').
  addE('memberOfGroup').from('user').
  addV('options').property('command_line_arguments','-D -n').
  addE('hasOptions').from('group')
```

Note that I set the properties with the `property` step as I prefer that form, but you can also add them directly with the `addV` step.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I have a janusgraph setup and the gremlin version with which it came is 3.2.3 and this query is not working in it. This kind of addV and addE came with 3.3.0 for bulk loading. Any other alternative which you can suggest? that would be great

Comment: You should keep the TinkerPop version aligned with the JanusGraph version. The syntax that Florian provided works on JanusGraph 0.1.1/TinkerPop 3.2.3 https://gist.github.com/pluradj/48a29692c07f700dc1350fcbb2b521f5

Comment: See JanusGraph version compatibility matrix http://docs.janusgraph.org/latest/version-compat.html

Comment: yes it works. did some mistake while editing the query variables. Thanks a lot @JasonPlurad and Florian. Highly appreciated :)